# WPF - Web Request being truncated

Tags: wpf, xml, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I'm using the bing api to request some results.. when I run my code the response string is truncated so that its missing the first 10-50 characters.. when I paste the exact same request in the browser it returns the results just fine..

Here is my code.. what am I doing wrong?

```
            string AppId = "My APP ID HERE :O ";
        string url = "http://api.search.live.net/xml.aspx?Appid={0}&sources={1}&query={2}";
        string completeUri = String.Format(url, AppId, "web", validateforweb(Artist) + "%20" + validateforweb(Song) + "%20" + "Lyrics");
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = null;
        webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(completeUri);
        HttpWebResponse webResponse = null;
        webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
        XmlReader xmlReader = null;
        Stream s = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
        xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(s);
        StreamReader reader;
        reader = new StreamReader(s);
        string str = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Why don't you try WebClient.DownloadString() instead. It's much cleaner. And will allow you to write less complex code. That means less errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it's related to the fact you're creating 2 readers on the stream (`XmlReader` and `StreamReader`). The `XmlReader` starts buffering data from the stream as soon as you create it, so when the `StreamReader` starts reading from the same stream, it misses the part of the data that has been buffered by the `XmlReader`.

You can't use 2 readers on the same stream, they will conflict with each other.